# Using python range objects to index into numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, array-indexing

I've seen it once or twice before, but I can't seem to find any official docs on it: Using python `range` objects as indices in numpy.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
a[range(3), range(2,-1,-1)]
# array([2, 4, 6])
```

Let's trigger an index error just to confirm that ranges are not in the official range (pun intended) of legal indexing methods:

```
a['x']

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Now, a slight divergence between numpy and its docs is not entirely unheard of and does not necessarily indicate that a feature is not intended (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48940730/7207392)).

So, does anybody know why this works at all? And if it is an intended feature what are the exact semantics / what is it good for? And are there any ND generalizations?

Comment: I've never seen this; is it used in any reputable libraries?

Comment: numpy predates Python 3.  In Python 2, `range(3)` is a list of integers, which numpy treats as "array-like".  It would have been a mess if numpy didn't also handle that in a backwards compatible way in Python 3.

Comment: *"So, does anybody know why this works at all?"*  It is a nice feature, informally called "fancy" indexing, and in the docs it is called [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser That's right, it says there `(...) a non-tuple sequence object` (although a `non-tuple sequence (such as a list) containing slice objects` will trigger basic indexing, it seems). Not sure why it should hang if  `IndexError` is not raised though, but whatever. I think you could make this an answer.

Comment: It could be that indexing tries `np.asarray(x)` with works with both `range(3)` and `[0,1,2]`.  Other things produce errors or object dtype arrays.  @WarrenWeckesser, makes a good point about compatibility with Py2's version of `range`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Hm, good point. I always forget that `range`s are sequences.

Comment: @jdehesa, I think this question is primarily about the use of `range` in the indexing tuple.  Ideally a multidimensional index is a tuple, but for backward compatibility some lists are interpreted as a tuples rather than an advanced indexing array.

Comment: Other Py3 sequence producers like generators, dictionary `keys`, `items`, map, don't work in either `np.array` or indexing.

Comment: You are just triggering fancy indexing. This is the same as writing `a[[0,1,2],[2,1,0]]` What is there to surprise?

Comment: @hpaulj strictly speaking those don't produce *sequences* as understood in python. Sequences are collections that implement `__len__` and take `int` objects for their `__getitem__`, (among a couple other methods like `__reversed__` and `.index`) but essentially things you can do `x[1]` and `len(x)` on. See the abstract base class here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes

Comment: We've had some past discussions of what it takes to be accepted as a sequence - that is, what methods a custom class has to implement to work in `np.array`.  One could construct such a minimal class, and see if it works as an advanced index.

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/a/48350240/901925, `Convertible` class works as an advanced index provided it's `__array__` uses `np.zeros(7, int)` (as opposed to the default floats).

Comment: `A()` in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037104/make-class-convertable-to-ndarray also works as an index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to wrap this up (thanks to @WarrenWeckesser in the comments): This behavior is actually documented. One only has to realize that `range` objects are python sequences [in the strict sense](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range).

So this is just a case of fancy indexing. Be warned, though, that it is very slow:

```
>>> a = np.arange(100000)
>>> timeit(lambda: a[range(100000)], number=1000)
12.969507368048653
>>> timeit(lambda: a[list(range(100000))], number=1000)
7.990526253008284
>>> timeit(lambda: a[np.arange(100000)], number=1000)
0.22483703796751797
```

Answer (score 1):

*Not a proper answer, but too long for comment.*

In fact, it seems to work with about any indexable object:

```
import numpy as np

class MyIndex:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if i < 0 or i >= self.n:
            raise IndexError
        return i
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(a[MyIndex(2)])
# [1 2]
```

I *think* the relevant lines in NumPy's code are below this comment in [`core/src/multiarray/mapping.c`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.3/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L286-L289):

```c
/*
 * Some other type of short sequence - assume we should unpack it like a
 * tuple, and then decide whether that was actually necessary.
 */
```

But I'm not entirely sure. For some reason, this hangs if you remove the `if i < 0 or i >= self.n: raise IndexError`, even though there is a `__len__`, so at some point it seems to be iterating through the given object until `IndexError` is raised.

Comment: It iterating would be consistent with that it is actually quite slow, for example compared to indexing with `arange`s.